# Is Jackson JSON schema module not supporting JSON Schema draft v4?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I'm generating JSON Schema for my Rest API's using Jackson Schema module, when started to implement JSON schema validation against requests to my APIs using https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator I realized that Jackson is generating schema v3 and the validator only supporting V4-draft.
Before move to look for other java JSON schema generator libs can you confirm Jackson is not supporting v4?
Can you please suggest other java JSON schema generator lib?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema](https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema) - It generates Json Schema draft 4 based on Jackson annotations

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not support Draft v4 JSON-Schema as is evident from their docs. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema. To generate JSON-Schema draft v4 the only option seems to be [JJSchema](https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema)